# How can I prove by induction that $\sum_{k=0}^n 2^{-k} = 1 - 2^-n$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

I have to prove by induction that

$$P(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n 2^{-k} = 1 - 2^{-n}$$

Base case: $2^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}$ and $1 - 2^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}$ so $P(1)$ is true.

Induction Step: Assuming $P(n)$ is true, show that the equality $P(n+1)$ is also true.

I did

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} 2^{-k} &= 2^{-1} + 2^{-2} + \dots + 2^{-n} + 2^{-(n+1)} \\
&= 1 - 2^{-n} + 2^{-(n+1)}
\end{align}

And then I did

\begin{align}
1 - 2^{-n} + 2^{-(n+1)} &= 1 - 2^{-n} + 2^{-n-1} \\
&= 1 - 2^{-n} + 2^{-n} \cdot 2^{-1} \\
&= 1 - 2^{-n} + \frac{2^{-n}}{2} \\
&= 1 - \frac {2 \cdot 2^{-n}}{2} + \frac{2^{-n}}{2} \\
&= 1 - \frac {2^{-n+1}}{2} + \frac{2^{-n}}{2} \\
&= 1 - \frac {2^{-n+1} + 2^{-n}}{2}
\end{align}

and then I don't know how to get $1 - 2^{-(n+1)}$. I feel like I made an error somewhere.

Comment: You did everything perfectly fine $$1-2^{-n}+2^{-n-1} = 1-2^{-n}(1-2^{-1}) = 1-2^{-n}(1/2) = 1-2^{-(n+1)}$$

Comment: Side note $2^k + 2^k = 2^{k+1}$, for all real $k$. Similarly $3^k + 3^k + 3^k = 3^{k+1}$

Comment: Thank you mattos and ok zoomer for the help! I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Note that very last step where you grouped the fractions has a sign error. Up until then you're fine.

Comment: Be careful with your index, you are summing from $k=1$, not $k=0$